# How do correctly benchmark my C program with optimization that might reorder my code?

Tags: c, gcc, embedded

I'm working on an embedded system, and I have my own timer function (`start_timer()` and `stop_timer()`). I'm hoping to time the following code precisely, but keep the optimization (`-O2`).

```
void loop() {
 uint16_t fram_cnt = 0;
 for (uint16_t i = 0; i < VEC_SIZE; i++) {
  fram_cnt += (fram_dst[i] == i);
 }
}

int main() {
 init();

 start_timer();
 loop();
 uint32_t time = stop_timer();
 msp_send_printf("loop time: %n", time);

 exit();
}
```

However, the value of `time` is always 0 with `-O2` on. My guess is that the compiler reorder my code because if I use `-O0` optimization, I can get correct time, and my CPU doesn't have out-of-order execution.

How can I correctly benchmark my program while keeping the same optimization level?

Comment: What does time represent? Are you sure it isn't just finishing before you have a single unit of time elapsed? There shouldn't be reordering that makes stop_timer execute before loop has completed. Maybe you should share the code for your timer functions.

Comment: you don't show the complete code so it' hard to guess but maybe the array `frame_dst` is known at compile time the whole `loop()` is optimized away

Comment: btw. even without `frame_dst` being known `loop()` is most probably optimized away because it only calculates `fram_cnt` and that value is never used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is being optimized out when you enable optimizations (as it does not have any observable effect) and the compiler will not even emit the call to it:

```
loop:
        bx      lr
.LC0:
        .ascii  "loop time: %n\000"
main:
        push    {r3, lr}
        bl      init
        bl      start_timer
        bl      stop_timer
        mov     r1, r0
        ldr     r0, .L5
        bl      msp_send_printf
        movs    r0, #1
        bl      exit
.L5:
        .word   .LC0
```

As a minimum remedy simple move the definition of the counter outside the function:

```
uint16_t fram_cnt = 0;

void loop() { 
 fram_cnt = 0;
 for (uint16_t i = 0; i < VEC_SIZE; i++) {
  fram_cnt += (fram_dst[i] == i);
 }
}
```

and it will be called and executed: https://godbolt.org/z/TY1sG3nPj

Comment: The loop could still be optimized out as the value in `fram_cnt` is never used, either.  Perhaps add a `printf()` after the `stop_timer()` call?

Comment: Thanks! I think you are right. I checked with the output assembly on my side. The `loop()` is optimized out. And your solution works.